# IE8 CSS width, can't use percents?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, width

Anyone have any problems with this? px and em work fine, % does nothing. I just want to extend this div the length of the screen in IE8. Microsoft, please. Been looking for a while to now avail.

CSS

```
#topPane {width:100%;
height:100px;
background-color:#0C9;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="topPane">a</div>
```

Comment: could it be that you have defined a width for a parent element? like html or body or another div that contains the #topPane ?

Comment: Works for me. What problem are you seeing? Does your code work in other browsers? You need to provide a more detailed description in order for people to help you.

Comment: your code would appear to suggest that you're trying to set the `height: 100px` rather than the `%` your question implies. Also, my own testing supports your point that `height: (n)%;` is invalid to IE 8 (Win XP). I don't know about versions < 8 though.

Comment: that was it exactly. though, specifically it was the position:absolute; tag in my body,html css combo definition. Gaby, you're radical.

Comment: ...ahh. You were using *length* to describe the *width* weren't you? I see... In which case, @Gaby should probably move that comment to an answer and it'd be polite for you, @Inserter, to accept that answer.

Comment: add at the top of the style block.
html,body{height:100%}

Answer (score 6):

by popular request :p i post my comment/answer

> could it be that you have defined a
>   width for a parent element? like html
>   or body or another div that contains
>   the #topPane ?

Comment: It just seems polite, you know? =)

Answer (score 0):

If we define width as 100% for parent and 90% fro the child like that further if there are futher childs elements. It should work right???